# Magento 2.2.5 : Custom option functionality work same as core in custom module

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I want to add custom option functionality in my custom module.

It should be working as like working in Magento 2 product view page.

Here, Custom option display in product view page. I want to the same structure and functionality in my custom module.

How to do in my custom module?

[image]